# adaptive compression with ffmpeg

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm currently developing an application which will enable visualizing images from different sources (mostly IP cameras) in browser (in a HTML5 video element). The UI will allow for matrix view so, normally 16 or more cameras will be displayed at the same time.
From cameras I get MJPEG streams or JPEG images (which I "convert" to MJPEG streams). So, for a camera, I have an MJPEG stream which I set as input for ffmpeg. I instruct ffmpeg to convert this to MP4 & H.264, and expose the output as a tcp stream, like this:

ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i "http://localhost/video.mjpg" -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 "tcp://127.0.0.1:5001?listen"

This works just fine on localhost, I get the stream displayed in the web page, at best quality.

But this has to work in various network conditions. I played a bit with chrome throttling settings, and noticed that if the network speed is just a bit below the required speed (given by the current compression settings I use in ffmpeg), the things start to go wrong: from stream start being delayed (so, no longer a live stream), up to complete freeze of 'live' image in browser.

What I need is an "adaptive" way to do the compression, in relation with current network speed.

My questions are:

- is ffmpeg able to handle this, to adapt to network conditions - automatically reduce compression quality when speed is low; so the image in browser will be lower quality, but live (which is most important in my case)
- if not, is there a way to workaround this?
- is there a way to detect the network bottleneck? (and then restart ffmpeg with lower compression parameters; this is not a dynamic adaptive streaming, but better than nothing)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: to get a live adaptive stream you're going to have to package as HLS or DASH. With ffmpeg I know you can do it for VOD, but not live multi-bitrate. That would have allowed the browser to handle the bitrate adaption. The messier solution would be to have ffmpeg jobs running to produce different bitrates and if you see the HTML5 video element buffer event firing step down to a lower bitrate source (not very smooth experience)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution do not work out of the local network. Why? because you must to use HTTP. For that the best solution is use HLS or DASH.

**HLS**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 640x360 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls index.m3u8
```

To generate adaptive streams you have to create an second level index. I do not explain here becaouse it is really clear in Apple doumentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH1-SW1

and in the standard: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-18

**DASH**

At the moment the FFMPEG not support Dash encoding. You can segment with FFMPEG ( [https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment][1] ) but i recomend that combine the FFMPEG and MP4Box. FFMPEG to transcode your live video and the MP4Box to segment and create the index .mpd.

MP4Box is a part of GPAC ( [http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/][2]  )

An example can be (using h264) - If you need vp8 (webm, use -vcodec libvpx and -f webm or -f ts ):

```
ffmpeg -threads 4 -f v4l2 -i  /dev/video0 -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -r 30 -s 1280x720  -f mp4 -y "$movie" > temp1.mp4 && MP4Box -dash 10000 -frag 1000 -rap "$movie"
```